# How to show text files results for code coverage in sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube

I have written unit cases for my adapter code. The results are in a text file having module name and whether the unit test is succcess or failure with the string SUCCESS AND FAILURE. How can I use this text file to show code coverage in sonarqube analysis ?. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to try to convert the into the [Generic Test Data format](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data). However, that format is designed to take coverage data about lines, not modules, so you may face difficulties with your data granularity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How to use it exactly. I am not able to find any samples. Can you please help me on this. Example of generic-coverage.xml with each fields and its explanation.

Comment: Hi , I want to set as covered as true for the entire folder level and not for linenumber. How to specify in that general xml format ?

Answer (score 0):

I want to set as covered as true for the entire folder level and not for linenumber. How to specify in that general xml format ? – Umap